# Enabling Paging in x86 Qemu

Tags: c, x86, paging, qemu

I am trying to enable paging on x86 architecture on Qemu.
But this code results into triple faults.

This code segment is executed in protected mode.
Code:  https://github.com/mridulv/simpleOperatingSystem

This is the Kernel Entry File

```
[bits 32]

[extern main]
[extern main2]
[extern page_table]

call main

lea ECX, [page_table - 0xC0000000]
mov CR3, ECX

mov ECX, CR0
or ECX, 0x80000000
mov CR0, ECX

;lea ECX, [StartInHigherHalf]
;jmp ECX

;StartInHigherHalf:
;   call main2

jmp $
```

This is the kernel file which created the page directory, tables.

```
unsigned int page_table[1024] __attribute__((aligned(4096)));;

void set_page_tables() {
    unsigned int pages_entry[1024 * 1024] __attribute__((aligned(4096)));

    unsigned int KERNEL_VIRTUAL_OFFSET = 0xC0000000;
    unsigned int KERNEL_FIRST_VIRTUAL_ADDRESS = 0xC0000000 >> 12;

    int numPageTables = 4;
    int numPagesInPageTable = 1024;
    int numPageTableEntriesInPageDirectory = 1024;
    int totalPages = numPageTables * numPagesInPageTable;

    unsigned int index = 0;
    unsigned int *pages_ptr = (unsigned int *)(pages_entry - KERNEL_VIRTUAL_OFFSET);
    unsigned int *page_table_ptr = (unsigned int *)(pages_entry - KERNEL_VIRTUAL_OFFSET);

    unsigned int positionAndFlags = 7;

    while (index < totalPages) {
        pages_ptr[index] = positionAndFlags;
        index = index + 1;
        positionAndFlags += 4096;
    }

    positionAndFlags = 7;
    index = KERNEL_FIRST_VIRTUAL_ADDRESS;
    unsigned int totalPagesLeft = KERNEL_FIRST_VIRTUAL_ADDRESS + totalPages;
    while (index < totalPagesLeft) {
        pages_ptr[index] = positionAndFlags;
        index = index + 1;
        positionAndFlags += 4096;
    }

    positionAndFlags = (unsigned int)&pages_ptr[0];
    positionAndFlags = positionAndFlags | 7;
    index = 0;
    while (index < numPageTableEntriesInPageDirectory) {
        page_table_ptr[index] = positionAndFlags;
        index = index + 1;
        positionAndFlags += 4096;
    }
}

void main() {
    char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8000;
    *video_memory = 'X';
    set_page_tables();
}

void main2() {
    char* video_memory = (char*) 0xb8004;
    *video_memory = 'Y';
    // __asm__ 
    // (
    //  "leal (page_table, ), %ecx\n\t" // 0xC0000000 = KERNEL_VIRTUAL_BASE
    //  "movl %cr3, %ecx"
    // );
}
```

Linker.ld

```
SECTIONS {
    . = 0xC0100000;

    .text : AT(ADDR(.text) - 0xC0000000) {
        *(.text);
    }

    . = ALIGN(0x1000);
    .bss : AT(ADDR(.bss) - 0xC0000000) {
        *(.text);
    }

    . = ALIGN(0x1000);
    .data : AT(ADDR(.data) - 0xC0000000) {
        *(.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of obvious things. You don't enable the [A20 line](http://wiki.osdev.org/A20_Line) that I can tell. In `boot.asm` at the start you save _DL_ (boot drive) and then place data (`PROTECTED_MODE_STR` and `BEGIN_STR`) right after. The CPU will try to execute the data. Place your data after all the code (try moving those to just before the boot signature). Another big issue is that you load your kernel at 0x1000 in memory. Your linker script uses a base of `0xC0100000` . This assumes your kernel was loaded at 0x100000 but you have yours at 0x1000. So in your case you may need `0xC0001000`

Comment: I haven't even looked beyond that. But you have enough problems before even getting to your code that tries to enable paging.

Comment: I also recommend changing things like `lea ECX, [page_table - 0xC0000000]` to `mov ECX, page_table - 0xC0000000`

Comment: As well since your code was initially running at memory address 0x1000, in order for code in the 0x1000 to 0x1FFF region to execute after enabling paging you will need to identity map the page. That means map the page with physical address 0x1000 to a 0x1000 virtual memory address. Failure to do this will make the code after paging is enabled fail

Comment: @MichaelPetch i am aligning different sections at 4kb ( 0x1000) which is different from loading at 0x100000

Comment: The problem is that you need to identity map the page where the code was originally loaded (0x1000 in your case). If you don't do that it will yield a protection fault when the code tries to continue after paging is enabled. That is because without identity mapping, the code will no longer be mapped into memory where it is expected. Among other things though that are wrong you put a multi megabyte structure (4mb with `unsigned int pages_entry[1024 * 1024] __attribute__((aligned(4096)));` on the stack but you put the stack in low memory where there isn't enough space.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to add the section declaration at the top of your code, to make things clear -

```
section .text
```

and the error in your code is that before executing

```
call main
```

your code does not (at all) setup a stack by filling in the ESP register.

To do this, your code should be like

1. Create a constant 'STACK_SIZE' like this -

   ```
   STACK_SIZE equ <valueOfSizeOfStack>
   ```
2. Create space for a stack

   ```
   section .bss
   kernelStack: RESB <valueOfSizeOfStack>
   ```

In the "valueOfSizeOfStack" field you can add 4096 (4-KB) or any multiple of it (not to large, it will count in your binary-size) for your stack.

Comment: At GitHub, search CircuitKernel for a full-fleged kernel example, which I am creating.